Jesus and the first commandment
Exodus 20:2-3 tells us:

I am the Lord your God, who brought you out of Egypt, out of the land of slavery. You shall have no other gods before me.

How do you reconcile this, the very first commandment given to Moses by God, with the idea that Jesus is God in human form? How is such a belief not a violation of the first commandment?

Well, if Jesus truly IS God, then there isn't a contradiction, right?

Also, welcome to Christianity.SE! This is a great first question.

This question - (which asked the same question) was closed because it did not specify to whom the question was addressed. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) in regard to the fact that on this site questions which can have multiple answers from various points of view are not permitted,

@NigelJ is correct. The LDS Church, for example, believes that Jesus and Jehovah were the same person (Jehovah being the pre-mortal name of Jesus Christ). Catholics believe Jesus and God the Father are the same person, resolving the conflict. Different denominations will have different view and answers. Not knowing which view you're looking to understand makes this out of scope.

@JBH - No, Catholics do not believe "Jesus and God the Father are the same person". They believe there are three persons in the  one Godhead.

@NigelJ The linked question and my own are not the same question all. My question is about God's commandment to put no other god's before Him. Essentially I'm asking how do you feel comfortable equating Jesus with God when the first commandment clearly says not to do that.

. . . .  but that is not how this site works. Please see the Tour and the Help. And please see the archive of 15,000 question/answer contributions. Your question can be answered in multiple ways by different viewpoints.

To emphasize what @LCIII said: The first commandment prohibits putting other gods before the true God. Jesus is the same God that gave the commandment, not another god.

You got the whole concept wrong to begin with, Jesus acquired the title Jesus after his mother named him according to the instructions of angel Gabriel. Before he acquired that title, he existed in spirit form as the eternal word.
John 8:57-58

Your father Abraham rejoiced that he would see my day. He saw it and was glad.” 57 So the Jews said to him, “You are not yet fifty years old, and have you seen Abraham?”[b] 58 Jesus said to them, “Truly, truly, I say to you, before Abraham was, I am.”

and in that eternal spirit form, he was also God, at least that is how John introduced us to him in the first chapter of his book. He says all things were created through the word(Jesus in spirit form before being incarnated into the flesh and the word was with God(The Most High) and the word was God
John 1:1

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.

God did not forbid anyone from worshipping Jesus for whoever glorifies or worships Jesus also glorifies the Father
John 17:1-5

Glorify your Son, that your Son may glorify you


People who follow Judaism do not accept and also struggle to understand the concept of Trinity, that Christians have with three "υποστάσεις". The Trinity is ONE and only God. That told shows zero contradiction.

@GeorgeEco, It is difficult at first but if you search the truth diligently then it is the true doctrine.

At first glance, the belief that Jesus is God incarnate may seem to present a contradiction to this commandment. But a deeper look will reveal that throughout the Old Testament, God appears in human-like forms, and the New Testament reveals that this very God is Jesus Christ.
Examples of God Appearing in Human-like Forms

Genesis 3:8 – "And they heard the voice of the Lord God walking in the garden in the cool of the day."

Genesis 18:1-2 – "And the Lord appeared unto him in the plains of Mamre... And he lift up his eyes and looked, and, lo, three men stood by him."

Genesis 32:24, 30 – "And Jacob was left alone; and there wrestled a man with him until the breaking of the day... And Jacob called the name of the place Peniel: for I have seen God face to face, and my life is preserved."

Exodus 3:2-6 – "And the angel of the Lord appeared unto him in a flame of fire out of the midst of a bush... And God called unto him out of the midst of the bush, and said, Moses, Moses... I am the God of thy father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob."

Exodus 33:11 – "And the Lord spake unto Moses face to face, as a man speaketh unto his friend."


There are many other examples throughout Scripture where God appears in human-like forms, but these are some significant ones, especially leading up to and surrounding the giving of the commandments.
Jesus is the One Who Appeared
The very individual who appeared to the people in the Old Testament was Jesus Christ. Jesus is not a separate deity but the one true God, fully divine and fully human. The New Testament confirms this in multiple ways:

Jude 1:5 – "I will therefore put you in remembrance, though ye once knew this, how Jesus, having saved the people out of the land of Egypt, afterward destroyed them that believed not."
Jude clearly states that it was the Jesus who saved the people out of Egypt, confirming that Jesus was the one acting in the Old Testament.

Matthew 9:2, 6 – "And, behold, they brought to him a man sick of the palsy... And Jesus seeing their faith said... Thy sins be forgiven thee... But that ye may know that the Son of man hath power on earth to forgive sins..."
Jesus forgives the man's sins and then declares that the Son of Man has the authority to forgive sins, linking His divine power to this messianic title.

Colossians 1:15 – "Who is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of every creature."
Jesus is the image of the invisible God, perfectly revealing God's nature, both fully human and fully divine.


Therefore, there is no violation of the First Commandment. Jesus is the same God who appeared to the patriarchs and led the Israelites, and He is the fulfillment of God's self-revelation. Jesus, fully God and fully man, is the one who revealed Himself in both human and divine forms throughout Scripture.

God appearing in human form is not the same thing as a man who claims to be God or other men claiming a man is God. The old testament examples speak of a clearly divine being allowing someone to see and interact with it. The new testament examples speak of men telling us that another man is divine. God's first commandment tells us not to put other gods before Him. Is it not a violation of the commandment to say that a man born on the earth is God himself?

@I0_ol Isaiah 9:6: “unto us a child is born, unto us a son is given: and the government shall be upon his shoulder: and his name shall be called Wonderful, Counsellor, The mighty God, The everlasting Father, The Prince of Peace”—it was prophesied that God himself would enter into humanity. It isn’t that “another man is divine”, the child born is the one and only divine God, which is the same entity which appeared before mankind in the OT.

@I0_ol "a violation of the commandment to say that a man born on the earth is God himself?".
Jesus was born as a human being, but before that he was an immortal spirit:
"Though he was God,
he did not think of equality with God
as something to cling to.
Instead, he gave up his divine privileges;
he took the humble position of a slave
and was born as a human being.
When he appeared in human form," (NLT).
Note that Jesus "was God", had "equality with God", and "was born as a human being". Quite explicitly, the human Jesus used to be God (and later regained his divinity).

@RayButterworth “For unto us a child is born, unto us a son is given: and the government shall be upon his shoulder: and his name shall be called Wonderful, Counsellor, The mighty God, The everlasting Father, The Prince of Peace.” Nothing about the prophecy of, or revealing of, Jesus Christ suggests he “used to be God”… Jesus never ceased being God. “In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God… And the Word was made flesh, and dwelt among us, (and we beheld his glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father,) full of grace and truth.”

The problem with this question is that it either misunderstands the doctrine it's arguing against or implicitly assumes that it's false, begging the question.
If Trinitarians believed that Jesus was born as a man and became another divine being, then yes, that would clearly violate the text you cited. But Trinitarians (maybe excluding some fringe groups) don't believe that. Rather, they believe that Jesus is and always has been fully God. Therefore the "me" of Exodus 20:2-3 therefore refers to the Trinity of Father, Son and Holy Spirit, and it follows that there is no violation of the commandment in worshipping God as God.
See for example the Westminster Confession of Faith:

2.1. There is but one only living and true God, who is infinite in being and perfection...


2.3. In the unity of the Godhead there be three Persons of one substance, power, and eternity: God the Father, God the Son, and God the Holy Ghost.


8.2. The Son of God, the second person in the Trinity, being very and eternal God, of one substance, and equal with the Father, did, when the fullness of time was come, take upon Him man’s nature, with all the essential properties and common infirmities thereof; yet without sin: being conceived by the power of the Holy Ghost, in the womb of the Virgin Mary, of her substance. So that two whole, perfect, and distinct natures, the Godhead and the manhood, were inseparably joined together in one person, without conversion, composition, or confusion. Which person is very God and very man, yet one Christ, the only mediator between God and man.


Jesus has already dealt with such ideas, objections and claims. Let him answer, with his own words. In this first real-life situation, Jesus had some of the Jewish people wanting to stone him to death for blasphemy.

"Therefore the Jews sought the more to kill him, because he not only
had broken the sabbath, but said also that God was  his Father, making
himself equal with God. Then answered Jesus and said unto them... For
as the Father raiseth up the dead, and quickeneth them, even so the
Son quickeneth whom he will. For the Father judgeth no man, but hath
committed all judgement unto the Son [cf. Psalm 50:6]; that all men
should honour the Son, even as thy honour the Father. He that
honoureth not the Son honoureth not the Father which hath sent him...
Do not think that I will accuse you to the Father: there is one that
accuseth you, even Moses, in whom ye trust. For had ye believed Moses,
ye would have believed me: for he wrote of me. But if ye believe not
his writings, how shall ye believe my words?" John 6:18-47 K.J.V.

And what did Moses write? He told the Israelites that God would send a prophet to them who they were to listen to and obey - Deuteronomy 18:15 - 19. Confirmed in Acts 3:20-26. Once you read what Moses foretold about this, you will see that God will require an accounting from any person who does not hearken unto that one, who will speak the very words of God. Jesus Christ was that foretold one.
Now read John 1:1-18 to realise just who this Jesus really is - the Word of God, who is God, who became flesh as the man Jesus. That is why Jesus accepted worship from people who discovered just who he really is; read John 20:26-29. He is God incarnate.
That is why giving Jesus the honour of worship is just the same as giving God the Father the honour of worship. There are not two Gods being worshipped, but the one God of Exodus 20. God spoke out of the burning bush to Moses to declare himself to be "The I Am". Exactly the same title Jesus took to himself (John 8:58).
